# How to convert PoseNet ResNet50 tfjs model into tflite?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to get this [PoseNet ResNet50 model](https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/tfjs-model/posenet/resnet50/float/1/default/1) working in Swift on iPhone XS. For that, I need to convert it to the tflite format. As I did not manage to find any direct way to do that; the most promising solution seems to be converting the tfjs model to `keras_saved_model` with the [tfjs converter](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/tree/master/tfjs-converter#getting-started) and then converting that to tflite using the [TensorFlow Lite converter](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert).

I struggle to convert to `keras_saved_model`. This is what I tried and how to reproduce the error:

- Download this model https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/tfjs-model/posenet/resnet50/float/1/default/1
- Open the downloaded folder and rename `model-stride32.json` to `model.json`
- Move back to the parent folder and run `tensorflowjs_wizard`
- Input the model path (`./posenet_resnet50_float_1_default_1`)
- You will see similar error to this:

```
Welcome to TensorFlow.js Converter.
? Please provide the path of model file or the directory that contains model files. 
If you are converting TFHub module please provide the URL.  ./posenet_resnet50_float_1_default_1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/daniel/anaconda3/envs/tfjs-graph-converter/bin/tensorflowjs_wizard", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(pip_main())
  File "/Users/daniel/anaconda3/envs/tfjs-graph-converter/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflowjs/converters/wizard.py", line 590, in pip_main
    main([' '.join(sys.argv[1:])])
  File "/Users/daniel/anaconda3/envs/tfjs-graph-converter/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflowjs/converters/wizard.py", line 598, in main
    run(dry_run)
  File "/Users/daniel/anaconda3/envs/tfjs-graph-converter/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflowjs/converters/wizard.py", line 410, in run
    input_params[common.INPUT_PATH])
  File "/Users/daniel/anaconda3/envs/tfjs-graph-converter/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflowjs/converters/wizard.py", line 107, in detect_input_format
    if get_tfjs_model_type(filename) == common.TFJS_LAYERS_MODEL_FORMAT:
  File "/Users/daniel/anaconda3/envs/tfjs-graph-converter/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflowjs/converters/wizard.py", line 67, in get_tfjs_model_type
    data = json.load(f)
  File "/Users/daniel/anaconda3/envs/tfjs-graph-converter/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "/Users/daniel/anaconda3/envs/tfjs-graph-converter/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte
```

TensorFlow.js 1.7.2
TensorFlow 2.1.0
macOS Catalina 10.15.5

I've also created [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/3477).

I appreciate any help on this:) Many thanks!